# Checking prop types in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the [React.Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) section in the official React documentation. Everything made sense except for the [part](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#proptypes) regarding `propTypes`. The docs state the following:

> In production mode, propTypes checks are skipped for efficiency.

Say I have the following code:

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
        );
    }
}

Sample.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Does the docs imply that in production my type checks against `props` will be skipped? If yes, how should I be checking prop types?

Comment: You should design an app that doesn't pass invalid types to your components ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't check against the prop types yourself at all, React does that for you.

However, as the docs say, only as long as you are in development mode. Every prop type check is essentially a function call that uses processing power and memory.

---

While you are in development, knowing that one of your props has the wrong type makes this cost a worthy trade-off.

**Once you are in production, your app should be tested thoroughly enough already that none of your prop type validations fail anymore anyway.**

For this reason, they are skipped to make your app a bit more  efficient instead.

Answer (score 2):

propTypes are only used to verify your current development process. You get notified via console logs when some required properties are missing, or the type of a property doesn't match the expected one.

There is no need to verify this type of validation in production builds. Missing properties don't break the rendering process, they just render your component in an unexpected way. But notice that your rendering process will fail, when you need to access properties of an "given" object.

To get in control over this unexpected behaviour, you should declare default properties.

However, working with the propTypes object and using unit tests is highly recommended to avoid unexpected rendering behaviour. Stick with it!

Comment: _Missing properties doesn't break the rendering process_ Usually, but then again, there is `cannot access property foo of undefined`.